# Header expiration in htaccess not working in sub-folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In a `.htaccess` the expiration headers are set (let's call it the primary htaccess file). Then in a specific folder of this I have another `.htaccess` file because I would like to have an exception and have different expiration headers for files in that subfolder. This subfolder contains `test.min.css`.

However, when testing it, the file `test.min.css` still has the expiration header of `max-age=9072000`, I assume coming from the `.htaccess` file a folder up.

What am I doing wrong in the `.htaccess` file in the subfolder?

The primary `.htaccess` file is as follows (it's a Wordpress site):

```
#Expires headers configuration added by BREEZE WP CACHE plugin
<IfModule mod_env.c>
   SetEnv BREEZE_BROWSER_CACHE_ON 1
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
   # Assets
   ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
   # Media assets 
   ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/bmp "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 year"
   # Font assets 
   ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType font/eot "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType font/woff "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 "access plus 1 year"
   # Data interchange
   ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
   ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"
   ExpiresByType application/ld+json "access plus 0 seconds"
   ExpiresByType application/schema+json "access plus 0 seconds"
   ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json "access plus 0 seconds"
   ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
   ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
   ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml "access plus 1 hour"
   ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"
   # Manifest files
   ExpiresByType application/manifest+json "access plus 1 week"
   ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json "access plus 0 seconds"
   ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest  "access plus 0 seconds"
   # Favicon
   ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 week"
   ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"
   # HTML no caching
   ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"
   # Other
   ExpiresByType application/xhtml-xml "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy "access plus 1 week"
</IfModule>
#End of expires headers configuration


RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.well-known/acme-challenge - [L]


# BEGIN Imagify: webp file type
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  AddType image/webp .webp
</IfModule>
# END Imagify: webp file type


# BEGIN Force https
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
# END Force https


# BEGIN Protect other domains trying to steal content
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)? [NC] 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?.*$ [NC]
# END Protect content (incl scorm) to be accessed from other domains


# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress


# MalCare WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
  </IfModule>
</Files>
# END MalCare WAF


# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
  </IfModule>
</Files>
# END Wordfence WAF
```

The `.htaccess` file that I added in the subfolder:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 hours"
   ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 6 hours"
</IfModule>
```

**Update:** I've removed the `<IfModule mod_expires.c>` wrapper.
The `mod_expires` module is enabled/installed.
The full header response is:

```
HTTP/2 200 OK
server: nginx
date: Fri, 14 Oct 2022 12:06:43 GMT
content-type: text/css
last-modified: Tue, 11 Oct 2022 19:41:25 GMT
vary: Accept-Encoding
etag: W/"63***425"
cache-control: public, max-age=9072000
content-encoding: gzip
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Comment: "still has the expiration header of `max-age=9072000`" - That's 3.5 months (105 days), so it doesn't look like it's coming from the the parent `.htaccess` file either. Please confirm the `Content-Type` you are seeing on the response, also the value of the `Server` header (if any). (Although even if the mime-type is wrong you would expect the `ExpiresDefault` to apply - and that's not being applied either, so it looks like something else is controlling the cache headers.) Is mod_expires enabled/installed? You should remove the `<IfModule mod_expires.c>` wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for these pointers, @MrWhite. I've removed the `<IfModule mod_expires.c>` wrapper and can confirm the `mod_expires` module is enabled. I've added the full header response to the original post. Very much appreciate it if you see any new pointers what might be causing this behaviour.

Comment: `server: nginx` - It looks like you may be behind a front-end proxy that is managing your static assets? This would also be responsible for the caching headers you are seeing. It's quite probable that Apache (your backend server) is bypassed entirely for such requests. Another look at your `.htaccess` file I see you are checking `X-Forwarded-Proto` in your "Force https" redirect - this confirms that you are behind a (Nginx) proxy server.

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite, I contacted the hosting provider and you were indeed right. They have now excluded the CSS and JS files from being served by Nginx. And as a result, now the .htaccess file works!

Comment: @MrWhite, do you want to add it as an answer?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've upgraded my comment(s) to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> still has the expiration header of `max-age=9072000`, I assume coming from the `.htaccess` file a folder up

Except that `9072000` *seconds* is 3.5 months (105 days), which doesn't appear to correspond to anything in the parent `.htaccess` file either.

> ```
> server: nginx
> ```

From the HTTP response headers for this request to your `.css` file it would seem the response is being served by an Nginx server, not your Apache back-end/application server.

This suggests that you are behind a front-end proxy that is perhaps managing your static assets. This would also be responsible for the caching headers you are seeing. It's quite probable that Apache (your back-end server) is bypassed entirely for such requests. This is a relatively common optimization, as Nginx is more performant for serving static assets.

In fact, after a closer look at your `.htaccess` file I see you are checking the `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP response header in your "Force https" redirect - this confirms that you are indeed behind a (Nginx) proxy server. (If you weren't then that rule would result in a redirect loop, since that header is never normally set, except by proxy servers.)

If this is the case then you would need to make an exception in the proxy server that allows these requests through to be proccessed by your back-end/Apache server.